# get newest records from database from a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a thread that looks for the newest records in a database and uses those for manipulation (using ODBC).

The problem I'm having is that when I manually insert two records into my database while the thread is running, it returns both records and then just the last one.

How can I get it to return just those 2 records?

Here is my code:

```
public void Run()
{
    // thread alive is set to true, in the main program it is set to false when the user quits
    while (RestTestThread.ThreadAlive)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);   // set to 1000 for quick testing
        try
        {
            // get the data from the database and return to a List<string>
            List<string> postList = Controllers.OdbcController.GetRecords();

            // convert that list into a string
            string post = string.Join(",", postList.ToArray());

            // format that data
            string postData = "{\"Data\":[" + post.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) + "]}";
            Program.postString.Clear();

            // test output
            Console.WriteLine(postData);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            break;
         }
    }
}
```

This is the Controllers.OdbcController.GetRecords() method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WatchItRDBMSService.Controllers
{
   public class OdbcController
   {
       private static string _lastId;
       private static string _dsn;  
       private static string _postData;
       private static OdbcConnection _connection;
       private static OdbcCommand _command;
       private static OdbcDataReader _reader;

       public static List<string> GetRecords()
       {
           List<string> result = new List<string>();
           _dsn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OdbcDsn"];

           if (_dsn != "")
           {
               if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LastId"] == "")
               {
                   // first read, initial, first run of the thread
           // create connection settings
                   string qry = String.Format("SELECT ID, TestValue FROM test.new_table");
                   _connection = new OdbcConnection(_dsn);
                   _connection.Open();
                   _command = _connection.CreateCommand();
                   _command.CommandText = qry;
                   _reader = _command.ExecuteReader();

                   while (_reader.Read())
                   {
                       _postData = String.Empty;
                       _postData += "{";

                       // rows exist (1 or more)
                       for (int i = 0; i < _reader.FieldCount; i++)
                       {
                           if (_postData.Length == 1)
                           {
                               _postData += String.Format("\"{0}\":\"{1}\"", _reader.GetName(i), _reader.GetValue(i));
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               _postData += String.Format(",\"{0}\":\"{1}\"", _reader.GetName(i), _reader.GetValue(i)); 
                           }
                       }
                       _postData += "}";

                       result.Add(_postData);

            // update the latest ID in App.config
                       _lastId = _reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                       Common.UpdateConfigFile.UpdateAppSetting("LastId", _lastId);
                   }

                   _reader.Close();
                   _command.Dispose();
                   _connection.Close();
               }
               else
               {
                   // successive reads, additions to table will be discovered here
           // set up database connections
                   string qry = String.Format("SELECT ID, TestValue FROM test.new_table WHERE ID > {0} ORDER BY ID DESC", Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LastId"]));
                   _connection = new OdbcConnection(_dsn);
                   _connection.Open();
                   _command = _connection.CreateCommand();
                   _command.CommandText = qry;
                   _reader = _command.ExecuteReader();

                   while (_reader.Read())
                   {
                       _postData = String.Empty;
                       _postData += "{";

                       // rows exist (1 or more)
                       for (int i = 0; i < _reader.FieldCount; i++)
                       {
                           if (_postData.Length == 1)
                           {
                               _postData += String.Format("\"{0}\":\"{1}\"", _reader.GetName(i), _reader.GetValue(i));
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               _postData += String.Format(",\"{0}\":\"{1}\"", _reader.GetName(i), _reader.GetValue(i));
                           }
                       }
                       _postData += "}";

                       result.Add(_postData);

              // update the latest ID in App.config
                       _lastId = _reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                       Common.UpdateConfigFile.UpdateAppSetting("LastId", _lastId);
                   }

                   _reader.Close();
                   _command.Dispose();
                   _connection.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No Database Connection(s) exist.");
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

My test table has `ID` & `TestValue` (`ID` is autoincrement)

For example, when I insert 2 values, say: `ID=17 TestValue="Test1", ID=18 TestValue="Test2"`

I get this:

```
{"Data": [{"ID":18, "TestValue":"Test2"}, {"ID":17, "TestValue":"Test1"}]}
{"Data": [{"ID":18, "TestValue":"Test2"}]}
```

But I only want:

```
{"Data": [{"ID":18, "TestValue":"Test2"}, {"ID":17, "TestValue":"Test1"}]}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Ok, thank you. I forgot about that sorry.

Comment: What does Controllers.OdbcController.GetRecords(); do?

Comment: That returns a list of records. I can include that in my question, it's a lot more code so I didn't do that initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was you, I would keep the last fetched `id` from the dataset.

Therefore you need to change your `Controllers.OdbcController.GetRecords()` to accept an `id` and return the latest one.

In the `GetRecords` check for that `id` using a `where` clause.

**EDIT:**

According to your update: are you sure the `ID` gets passed to the config correctly?

You use two different calls to save and retrieve:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LastId"]
```

vs.

```
Common.UpdateConfigFile.UpdateAppSetting("LastId", _lastId)
```

Why not use this?

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LastId"] = _lastId;
```

Comment: In my GetRecords() method, I already had a where clause and I was getting the ID from an app.config file. The method is also saving that ID in the app.config file when the query executes. I've edited my question with the GetRecords() method.

Comment: UpdateAppSetting does this: `public static void UpdateAppSetting(string key, string value)
        {
            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(key);
            config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, value);

            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
        }` I tested to see that it updates the Id and it does

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use the C# lock object. Lock object prevents the critical area being accessed by only one thread.

```
private object lockObj=new object();

public void Run()
{
// thread alive is set to true, in the main program it is set to false when the user quits
while (RestTestThread.ThreadAlive)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);   // set to 1000 for quick testing
    try
    {
        lock(lockObj)
       {
           // get the data from the database and return to a List<string>
           List<string> postList = Controllers.OdbcController.GetRecords();

           // convert that list into a string
           string post = string.Join(",", postList.ToArray());

           // format that data
          string postData = "{\"Data\":[" + post.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) + "]}";
          Program.postString.Clear();

          // test output
          Console.WriteLine(postData);
       }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        break;
     }
}
```

}

Comment: Where is nothing to lock since this is just a `while` loop.

Comment: That still returns those 2 lines I was describing.